Randomness in RAM
Is there a problem on $n$ bits that can be solved in linear time on a RAM with randomness, but we don't know how to solve in linear time without randomness?
Exclude polynomial-identity testing (see Louis' answer below).  I'm looking for something basic, perhaps similar to element distinctness.
The RAM model I'm interested in has $\log n$-bit registers.  I can allow for a little more, but not $c \log n$.  Equivalently, I allow for $c \log n$-bit registers but I insist that the memory used is linear.
I don't think element distinctness qualifies.  It would if I allowed for $n$ cells as input, but not sure with bits.  Though maybe there's a variant that does qualify.

Can you be more specific about what you would accept for "solved"?  E.g. do you mean a decision problem?  Does the answer have to be correct (and the expected running time linear)?  Or does the answer only have to be correct with high (or greater than 2/3) probability?  Etc.  You mention linear time.  Do you intend to preclude padded problems (e.g., if there is a problem with a quadratic-time randomized algorithm but no known quadratic-time deterministic algorithm, you could artificially pad the inputs to turn the problem into one with a linear-time randomized alg...)?

I was hoping decision problem, and "simple" like element distinctness or something like that, and say error probability 1/3.

I'm confused by "insist that the memory used is linear".  Given that you are asking about linear-time algorithms, wouldn't they generally use at most linear space?

Related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/11738/8237 (one of the answers mentions that there is a sub-linear time algorithm for approximating the value of a two-player zero-sum game in a certain way, but no such deterministic algorithm).  An easier example in this spirit is, given an array of $n$ 0/1 values, to estimate the number of entries that are ones, with, say, multiplicative error at most 0.01, with probability at least 2/3.

With clog n-bit registers you can index memory location $n^2$, say.  The estimation problem doesn't work because it can be solved in linear deterministic time.  (It shows a different type of separation that I'm asking.)

I think Polynomial identity testing fits the question. If you have the right encoding for polynomials, you can test the equality by evaluating the polynomials on random values in linear time over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for a random large $p$. We don't know how to do that in polynomial time without randomness (and therefore the result is stronger than just linear time).

Yes I should have been clear on this, is there anything else more similar to element distinctness?  Actually I don't think you need any specific encoding, since as you say it is not known to be in P (so even if I consider polynomials in $n^{0.1}$ variables it's still not clear how to do it in linear time).  I updated the question.

Second proposition: Freivalds' algorithm. The complexity is $O(n^2)$  but here the input is $O(n^2)$ so it is actually linear.

Freivalds' algorithm fits my bill so I'll accept this answer.

Note that Freivalds algorithm is just PIT on quadratic polynomials. You can also consider a problem like: given a circuit of size n and degree n in one variable, is it identically zero? Now it's a quadratic time problem deterministically. Getting subquadratic time without randomness refutes the Non-deterministic SETH.

Yes, but the formulation with matrices is cleaner and doesn't need finite fields etc.  Can you give me a pointer to this problem you are mentioning and the connection to SETH?  Also, I was hoping that element distinctness was such an example, but there's an annoying issue whether the input is given in bits or words; I don't see it gives such a separation for bits.
